# Need help parallelising the ran2 and main program causing segmentation fault openmp

Tags: c, random, parallel-processing, openmp, random-seed

I tried to parallelize the loop but increasing the thread count leave me with 'Segmentation fault(core dumped)'

I have parallelized the loop in the main.c, the loop internally refers to the ran2.c file function, which somewhere leads me to the segmentation fault, I need help parallelizing the program.

main.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int niter, i, j;
    long seed;
    double count;
    double x,y,z,pi;
    extern float ran2();
    niter=10000;
    count=0;

    #pragma omp parallel firstprivate(x, y, z, i) shared(count) num_threads(4)
    for(i=1; i<=niter; i++) {
        seed=i;
        x=ran2(&seed);
        y=ran2(&seed);
        z=x*x+y*y;
        if(z<1) {
            count+=1;
        }
    }
    pi=count*4.0/niter;
    printf("The value of pi is %8.14f\n",pi);
    return 0;
}
```

ran2.c

```
#define IM2 2147483399
#define IM1 2147483563
#define AM (1.0/IM1)
#define IMM1 (IM1-1)
#define IA1 40014
#define IA2 40692
#define IQ1 53668
#define IQ2 52774
#define IR1 12211
#define IR2 3791
#define NTAB 32
#define NDIV (1+IMM1/NTAB)
#define EPS 1.2e-7
#define RNMX (1.0-EPS)

float ran2(long *idum) {
    int j;
    long k;
    static long idum2=123456789;
    static long iy=0;
    static long iv[NTAB];
    float temp;
    if (*idum <= 0) {
        if (-(*idum) < 1)
            *idum=1;
        else *idum = -(*idum);
        idum2=(*idum);
        for (j=NTAB+7; j>=0; j--) {
            k=(*idum)/IQ1;
            *idum=IA1*(*idum-k*IQ1)-k*IR1;
            if (*idum < 0)
                *idum += IM1;
            if (j < NTAB)
                iv[j] = *idum;
        }
        iy=iv[0];
    }
    k=(*idum)/IQ1;
    *idum=IA1*(*idum-k*IQ1)-k*IR1;
    if (*idum < 0)
        *idum += IM1;
    k=idum2/IQ2;
    idum2=IA2*(idum2-k*IQ2)-k*IR2;
    if (idum2 < 0)
        idum2 += IM2;
    j=iy/NDIV;
    iy=iv[j]-idum2;
    iv[j] = *idum;
    if (iy < 1)
        iy += IMM1;
    if ((temp=AM*iy) > RNMX)
        return RNMX;
    else
        return temp;
}
```

I need to parallelize the program.

Comment: Your `ran2` function is not thread safe.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm is that the reason for segmentation fault?

Comment: Probably.  You're using `iy` to compute index `j`, but it looks like `iy` can be negative and if another thread set it that way bad stuff can happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random number generator of L'Ecuyer with Bays-Durham](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56697829/random-number-generator-of-lecuyer-with-bays-durham)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has several problems.

First of all, you are passing the uninitialized values of `x`, `y`, and `z` to each OpenMP thread with `firstprivate`, which the compiler warns about. This is easy to work around by moving the declarations inside to `for` loop and removing the `firstprivate`. For the same reason, `i` should be `private`.

`seed` is supposed to stay the same during each iteration, but since it is a shared variable, the threads are competing to get their value written to it. This is also fixed by moving the declaration of `seed` into the loop.

The third problem is that the threads are also racing when writing to `count`. Since you want to sum up the values from the different threads, you should be using the `reduction(+:count)` directive.

Fourth, the `ran2` function is not thread-safe. It has static state in the form of `idum2`, `iy`, and `iv`, where again the threads race. The best way to fix this is to get rid of the global state by moving it into a `struct ran_state` (see below) which is passed as a parameter. Then replace each place referring to `idum2` with `state->idum2`, `iy` with `iy` and `state->iv` with `state->iv`. Finally, create and initialize this state before the `for` loop, and mark it as `firstprivate` so each thread gets its own initialized state.

This then looks as below (in one file for convenience):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Insert the #defines for ran2 here ...

struct ran_state {
    long idum2;
    long iy;
    long iv[NTAB];
};

// Insert ran2 here, replacing iv with state->iv, and so on ...

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int niter, i;
    double count;
    double pi;
    niter=10000;
    count=0;
    struct ran_state state = { 123456789, 0, {0} };

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:count) firstprivate(state) private(i) num_threads(4)
    for(i=1;i<=niter;i++){
        double x, y, z;
        long seed;
        seed=i;
        x=ran2(&seed, &state);
        y=ran2(&seed, &state);
        z=x*x+y*y;
        if(z<1){
            count+=1;
        }
    }
    pi=count*4.0/niter;
    printf("The value of pi is %8.14f\n",pi);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @rtoikala thanks, most of the problem got solved, but there is a concern, as the number of threads changes the value varies a little, is that correct? if so I want to know why?

Comment: I suspect it is because different random numbers are being generated with different numbers of threads, which would not be a  problem.

Comment: Rather than shifting seed in the loop, consider it making private. Just an OpenMP way of saying, this variable is private to each thread! Essentially the similar way @rtoijala mentions but more close to OpenMP